# insert variable value in lambda expression python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I am trying to get the variable value into the lambda function , but it seems not to work and ignore the value with no error.

```
a_name = ['APP-1 extension check', 'APP-1 b2b check', 'APP-1 no checks']
ape_t = content['data'] # ape_t contains result APP-1
ape_d = str(ape_t) # this becomes 'APP-1'
ape_f = ape_d + ' ' # this becomes 'APP-1 '

tempda=list(map(lambda x: x.replace(ape_f,''),a_name)) # here I want to get the variable value of ape_d 
which is 'APP-1 '
```

when I run this I **expect** my output to be 
`['extension check', 'b2b check', 'no checks']`

But instead it gives the **current** output
`['APP-1 extension check', 'APP-1 b2b check', 'APP-1 no checks']`

Is there anything missing here, any help would be great.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I get the expected output.

Comment: can't you just do `[item.split(' ', 1)[-1] for item in a_name]` ?

Comment: can you show a sample of content?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If I run your code it results in your expected output, so I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. First verify that `ape_f` contains the string you expect. Then if you want to see original list `a_name` to be modified, assign the modification back to `a_name`. 
Change 
`tempda=list(map(lambda x: x.replace(ape_f,''),a_name))` 
to 
`a_name=list(map(lambda x: x.replace(ape_f,''),a_name))`
 

Hope this helps!